# Making a conditional tab bar in ios

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I'm working on an IOS app that uses tabs for navigation. The app gives access to users to a video library. However there are two types of users, those who purchase individual episodes and those who are subscribed. The former only have access to the videos they purchased while the latter have access to every single video in the library.

In my tab bar (in storyboard) I have a Purchases button, but if the user is a subscriber I don't want this tab to appear.

The app checks if a user is logged in upon launching and checks to see what the user status is (buyer or subscriber). I would like to know if there is a way to load different sets of tabs depending on the user type.

If any one could steer me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UITabBarController and use `setViewControllers(_:animated:)`:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController 
{

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switch user
        {
        case .buyer:
            guard let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first"),
                  let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") else
            {
                return
            }

            setViewControllers([vc1, vc2], animated: true)

        case .subscriber:
            guard let vc3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third"),
                  let vc4 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fourth") else
            {
                return
            }

            setViewControllers([vc3, vc4], animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head I can think of several ways but this could do it. I am assuming that you somehow know which kind of user is logged in based on the server's response or something similar.

1. Create your own class that mutates depending on the user eg:

   ```
   MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if (currentUser == admin) {
          setupAdminTabBar()
        } else { 
          setupRegularTabBar()
        }
     }
   }
   ```

then on each function do something like

```
func setupRegularTabBar() {
//do this many as many times as root view controllers you want
    let searchNavController = createMyNavController(unselectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourimage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "yourimage"), rootViewController: UserSearchController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
//add the other controllers that you create like the one above...
  viewControllers = [searchNavController]
}

fileprivate func createMyNavController (unselectedImage: UIImage, selectedImage: UIImage, rootViewController : UIViewController = UIViewController()) -> UINavigationController {
        let viewController = rootViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navController.tabBarItem.image = unselectedImage
        navController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage
        return navController
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setViewControllers` function of UITabBarController:

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, animated: Bool)
```

Set up all the possible controllers in the storyboard with a separate outlet for each one. Then pass an array of the outlets you wish to appear to `setViewControllers`